# How to Delete the Old Contents of a Zip File When Making a New Zip

Tags: linux, zip

Currently I'm using the following command to zip all my folders and files with the exception of a few.

```
zip -r  Archive.zip . -x '*.git*' '*.DS_Store*' '*.pyc*'
```

The problem with this command is it doesn't delete files in the older zip file that I deleted.

So I know that I can just run the rm command on the zip file before making a new one. However, I wanted to see if there's a way I can essentially combine the zip command above with an rm command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete a specific file from zip archive with `-d` flag

```
-d
--delete
Remove (delete) entries from a zip archive. For example:

zip  -d  foo  foo/tom/junk  foo/harry/\*  \*.o
```

Comment: So essentially I can do this?
    zip -d . -r  Archive.zip . -x '*.git*' '*.DS_Store*' '*.pyc*'

Comment: try with `zip -d file.zip "*"` if you want to remove everything from file archive

Comment: I see, so there's no way to combine -d and -r into one command?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be possible, cannot check it right now, as don't have a `*nix` system on the desk